# How can velocity of water remain constant for a vertical cylindrical tube?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, energy-conservation

I have got a question in the Physics textbook which is as follows:

> Water enters through end A with speed v<sub>1</sub> and leaves through end B with speed v<sub>2</sub>  of a cylindrical tube AB. The tube is always completely filled with water. In case I the tube is horizontal, in case II it is vertical with A upwards and in case III it is vertical with end B upward. For which case(s) is v<sub>1</sub> = v<sub>2</sub> true?

Now apparently the answer is that it is true in all cases with the reasoning being the equation of continuity.

$a_1v_1 = a_2v_2$

Now, this does make sense with areas being equal in all cases and therefore the velocities also become equal.

But thinking about it without using the formulas it makes no sense as obviously gravity will accelerate the water.

Coming back to formulas, why can't we use Bernoulli's Theorem here which also supports the same thing I mentioned in the above paragraph?

$P + \frac1 2 \rho v^2 + \rho gh = constant$

Here I don't see a reason for pressure to change so that leaves out the kinetic energy and potential energy, and in case II and III, there definitely have to be an exchange between those.

So how are the velocities the same at the two ends in cases II and III?

Am I missing something here or getting something wrong?

Comment: Bear in mind that the question assumes that the fluid is _incompressible_. So even if there are forces, provided the area is the same on either end, $v_1=v_2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Water is almost always modelled as being incompressible. And as joseph h commented, incompressibility together with the equation of continuity is enough to determine that $v_1 = v_2$.

You are puzzled by the fact that in one situation we have no pressure difference introduced by gravity in the tube and in another situation we have a hydrostatic pressure from gravitational forces. But you need to be aware that we only have partial information on the pressures. We haven't talked about viscous forces that would cause a pressure drop along the tube, we haven't talked about what is driving the flow (maybe there is a pump at one end that causes high pressure...?). The point is that we don't need to, because continuity alone yields the answer.